# Слияние python с Minecraft

Tags: python, калькулятор

Есть сервер, на котором время от времени в чат пишется пример, за решение которого получаешь валюту.  Я смог написать код для решения этих примеров на python, используя логи.

Требуется, чтобы ответ как-то автоматически писался в чат.

Но я не знаю, как это сделать, так как только день назад начал вникать в эту тему.

Сервер не мой, сделан через лаунчер (с модами), но, думаю, если постараться, то можно обойти защиту.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это всё организовать.

Answer (score 0):

Для майнкрафта не пишу, за две минуты [нашел вот этот код](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zX0wlSIhQ6w), попробуйте:

```
from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft

mc = Minecraft.create()
mc.postToChat("Привет от FelikMine!")
```

Comment: Сервер не мой, а для использивания mcpi.minecraft роботает лишь на своем серве.Ну или я что-то не понимаю. Но у меня ето не работает

Comment: В таком случае вас интересует не программирование, а хакерство: 1) устанавливаете Wireshark или любое другое ПО для перехвата сетевого трафика; 2) Запускаете его и настраиваете для прослушки сетевого трафика майнкрафт; 3) Отправляете сообщение в чат и находите в каком формате и куда это сообщение ушло. Пытаетесь отправить новое сообщение через Wireshark; 4) Автоматизируете процесс с помощью языка программирования; 5) Повторите процесс с входящими сообщениями из чата.

Comment: Одна маленькая ремарка: если соединение с сервером защищено (шифруется с помощью сертификата безопасности), то как с этим быть я не готов вам сказать. Скорее всего никак вам с этим не быть